# How can I keep the name of user logged vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Im trying to store the user logged on my application. Im using a store.js file to use vuex and save my variables.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'


Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    userloged: ''
  }
})
```

I declared the store variable on my main.js and I used in this way, when I save the name of the user in my login component I use,

```
        this.$store.state.userloged = this.username;
```

And when Im going to used in the others components I got it in this way,

```
 computed:{
    userloged() {
        return this.$store.state.userloged;
    }
},
```

But if I refresh the page I lost the information.
What can I do?

Comment: I added an example on my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `'vuex-persistedstate'` to persist Vuex state with localStorage.

You should update the state through mutations and dispatching an action, redifine your vuex instance to contain the following objects:

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate';

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    userlogged: ''
  },
  mutations: {
    saveUserLogged (state, loggedUser) {
      state.userLogged = loggedUser
    }
  },
  actions: {
    saveUserLogged (context, loggedUser) {
      context.commit('saveUserLogged', loggedUser)
    }
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState()]
})
```

So to save the loggedUser you should dispatch an action:

```
this.$store.dispatch('saveUserLogged', this.username);
```

You can learn more about mutations and actions in the [Vuex official site](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/core-concepts.html)

Please take a look to this example https://codesandbox.io/s/0yy7vk29kv

Comment: This won't help when the page is refreshed as the state is in memory not saved in any way.

Answer (score 2):

Vuex doesn't persist the state over page reloads.

You have to use something like [Vuex-persistedstate plugin](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate).

```
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // ...
  plugins: [createPersistedState()]
})
```

Docs and instalation instructions: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate

Comment: I read about it but, still doesnt work.  
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'


Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    userloged: ''
  },
    plugins: [
    createPersistedState({
      storage: {
        getItem: key => Cookies.get(key),
        setItem: (key, value) => Cookies.set(key, value, {
          expires: 3,
          secure: true
        }),
        removeItem: key => Cookies.remove(key)
      }
    })
  ]
})

Comment: I include the plugin but, when I refresh the page I cant get the username. I dont understand how can I use the plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the cookies with
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies